# EF Core Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, миграция

Есть проект asp net core 3.1 mvc. Используется подход Code First. Заметил что при изменении модели и создании новой миграции (Add-Migration Name) получается ошибка

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IModel source, IModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Соответственно после этого не могу удалить предыдущий миграцию (Remove-Migration) - получаю соответствующую ошибку.

Возможно я ошибаюсь, но как я понимаю ошибка связанна с тем что я удаляю в модели внешний ключ (просто удаляю свойство). Как правильно поступить в данной ситуации? Руками исправлять файл предыдущей миграции?

Comment: ef core 2.1? Попробуйте обновить или [почитать](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13529)

Comment: ef 3.1 тоже, эту статью видел, не помогло